# Full height two column page using Bootstrap 5 but without cards in them

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to make a two column full height page and I don't wish to use cards since there's going to be no images but a whole lot of text, links and buttons in the halves. I am not even sure if that is possible with Bootstrap columns but if there is a way kindly help by publishing the code for the same below. To be precise, the problem is that the columns are stuck at the top of the container and I am unable to stretch them to fill the entire page.

What I have right now:

```
 <div class="container-xxl text-center" style="margin: 20px auto 20px auto;">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg text-bg-light">
                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg text-bg-secondary">
                    
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

Add the `vh-100` class (`100vh` will be `100%` of the **viewport height**). Read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport).

```css
.col-lg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-xxl text-center" style="margin: 20px auto 20px auto;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg text-bg-light vh-100">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg text-bg-secondary vh-100">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```